# Multithreading: do I need protect my variable in read-only method?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, locking, c++11

I have few questions about using lock to protect my shared data structure. I am  using C/C++/ObjC/Objc++

For example I have a counter class that used in multi-thread environment

```
class MyCounter {
private:
    int counter;
    std::mutex m;

public:
    int getCount() const {
        return counter;
    }
    void increase() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        counter++;
    }
};
```

1. Do I need to use `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);` in `getCount()` method to make it thread-safe?
2. What happen if there is only two threads: a reader thread and a writer thread then do I have to protect it at all? Because there is only one thread is modifying the variable so I think no lost update will happen.
3. If there are multiple writer/reader for a shared primitive type variable (e.g. `int`) what disaster may happen if I only lock in write method but not read method? Will 8bits type make any difference compare to 64bits type?
4. Is any primitive type are atomic by default? For example write to a `char` is always atomic? (I know this is true in Java but don't know about c++ and I am using llvm compiler on Mac if platform matters)

Comment: "C/C++/ObjC/Objc++" These are all completely different languages. Pick one; you seem to have picked C++.

Comment: I am using ObjC for GUI and C++ for backend and ObjC++ to combine them. Also ObjC++ is superset of others. I just pick C++ as example.

Comment: That's good, but don't combine them into a list as one. :) Just say you're interested in an answer in four different languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, unless you can guarantee that changes to the underlying variable `counter` are atomic, you need the mutex.

Classic example, say `counter` is a two-byte value that's incremented in (non-atomic) stages:

```
(a) add 1 to lower byte
    if lower byte is 0:
(b)     add 1 to upper byte
```

and the initial value is 255.

If another thread comes in anywhere between the lower byte change `a` and the upper byte change `b`, it will read 0 rather than the correct 255 (pre-increment) or 256 (post-increment).

In terms of what data types are atomic, the latest C++ standard defines them in the `<atomic>` header.

If you *don't* have C++11 capabilities, then it's down to the implementation what types are atomic.

Comment: I was thinking we are using 32/64bits CPU which should update a 32bits size variable at a time with out divided it into two steps?

Comment: @xlc0212, the operative word there is "should". By all means, if you can verify that, you may be okay. But it's not just a simple matter of threads on one CPU, you may be using multiple CPUs, interrupts, and all sorts of other wondrous stuff happening under the covers.

Comment: @xlc0212 that won't work (reliably/predictably); what you have is sequential consistency, not strict consistency. what you observe if treating sequential as strict will be "close, but not quite", and the  program will just have nasty bugs.

Comment: Even if atomic you still need it to ensure the proper visibility of `counter`, otherwise you could be seeing old values. I guess if you're okay with seeing old values you'd be fine.

Comment: +1 for the "old values" comment. In many cases it's fine (threads run independently anyway, if the scheduling would have been different the same value would have been current) but you need to explicitly consider this.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y The CPU cache will not in general allow "old" values to be seen; but other execution artefacts might.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would need to lock the read as well in this case.

There are several alternatives -- a lock is quite heavy here. Atomic operations are the most obvious (lock-free). There are also other approaches to locking in this design -- the read write lock is one example.

Comment: +1, but just as a note: `std::atomic` types in c++ are not guaranteed to be lock free. They will most likely be lock free for integers on most platforms, but it is not an explicit guarantee (you can check for it however).

Comment: +1 for @KillianDS comment but keep in mind that atomic types are atomic, whether lock-free or not. If an underlying platform has lock-free capability, the atomics will (almost certainly and, if they don't, you should switch to a better compiler) use it. Otherwise it'll lock. Atomicity will still be there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that you do need to lock the read as well. But since you are using C++11 features, why don't you use `std::atomic<int> counter;` instead?

Comment: thats another problem: `#error <atomic> is not implemented`. This happened if I try to `#include <atomic>`

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you should lock the read too. 
Read and write to int is atomic on most architecture (and since `int` is guaranted to be the machine's word size, you should almost never experience corrupted int)

Yet, the answer from @paxdiablo is correct, and will happen if you have someone doing this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
  struct MyObj
  {
     char a; 
     MyCounter cnt;
  };
#pragma pack(pop)
```

In that specific case, `cnt` will not be aligned to a word boundary, and the `int MyCounter::counter` will/might be emulated in multiple operations in CPU supporting unaligned access (like x86). Thus, you could get this sequence of operations:

```
Thread A:   [...] set counter to 255 (counter is 0x000000FF)
            getCount() => CPU reads low byte: lo:255
<interrupted here>
Thread B:   increase() => counter is incremented, leading to counter = 256 = 0x00000100)
<interrupted here>
Thread A:   CPU read high bytes: 0x000001, concatenate: 0x000001FF, returns 511 !
```

Now, let's say you never use unaligned access. Yet, if you are doing something like this:

```
   ThreadA.cpp: 
   int g = clientCounter.getCount();
   while (g > 0)
   {
      processFirstClient();
      g = clientCounter.getCount();     
   }

   ThreadB.cpp:
   if (acceptClient()) clientCounter.increase();
```

The compiler is completely allowed to replace the loop in Thread A by this:

```
if (clientCounter.getCount()) 
   while(true) processFirstClient();
```

Why ? That's because for each instruction, the compiler will evaluate side-effects of such expression. The `getCount()` is so simple that the compiler will deduce: it's a read of a single variable, and it's not modified anywhere in ThreadA.cpp, thus, it's constant. Because it's constant, let's simplify this.

If you add a mutex, the mutex code will insert a memory barrier telling the compiler "hey, don't expect anything after this barrier is crossed". 
Thus, the "optimization" above can not happen since `getCount` might have been modified.

Sure, you could have written `volatile int counter` instead of `counter`, and the compiler would have avoided this optimization too.

In the end, if you have to write a ton of code just to avoid a mutex, you're doing it wrong (and probably will get wrong results).

Answer (score -1):

You cant gaurantee that multiple threads wont modify your variable at the same time. and if such a situation occurs your variable will be garbled or program might crash. In order to avoid such cases its always better and safer to make the program thread safe.

You can use the synchronization techinques available like: Mutex, Lock, Synchronization attribute(available for MS c++)

Comment: He did actually guarantee that multiple threads can't write at the same time. It is still not correct to omit a read-lock but for other reasons (posted in other answers).

Comment: How can he be so sure in a multi threaded situation without using synchronization?

Comment: `increase` (the only non-const method) does use synchronization, and the shared data is `private`

Comment: @Rohit because I only have a GUI thread (main thread) that only read variable (one reader) and a background thread used to update variable (only one writer).

Comment: What if multiple instance are running of the app?

Comment: @Rohit: Unless you use something like [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) each program instance has its' own restricted memory space and its' own instance of that variable. The variable only needs to be protected within that process' instance.