# Is comparing 2 int's an atomic operation?

Tags: c++, gcc, atomic

I'm writing a very simple atomic counter, like

```
class counter
{
    /* ... */

    int increment()
    {
        return __sync_add_and_fetch( &counter_, 1 );
    }
    int decrement()
    {
        return __sync_sub_and_fetch( &counter_, 1 );
    }
    bool operator==( int val ) // const
    {
        return __sync_bool_compare_and_swap( &counter_, val, counter_ );
    }

private:
    volatile int counter_;
};
```

Can I use `return counter_ == val;` inside my `operator==` (shorter and will be able to uncomment the `const` qualifier)? Or I should use `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` instead?

---

**Edit:** So, I'm more confused than in the beginning. After reading the comments and answers, I think leaving the "compare-and-swap" is more adequate. Is it?

**Edit 2:** I get rid of this `operator==`, but I'm still curious. I'll wait and hope for a bit more activity on this question. Thanks.

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834752/multithreading-do-i-need-protect-my-variable-in-read-only-method

Comment: why would you compare and swap? That and `operator==` are two *different* things...(?) Surely, you would *fetch* the two values and simply compare them?

Comment: @BryanChen - actually, you're right.. I should've thought about this comparing as "reading" of the var.

Comment: It depends on whether or not reading the value is atomic. Is it?

Comment: Please just use atomics for atomics.

Comment: @Nim - I'm actually swapping the var with itself. I just need a comparing, but I don't see any built-in functions about this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - right and I was just going to delete the question and leave the `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`, but now I'm confused.

Comment: If you know that reading an aligned `int` is atomic on any supported platform then using `==` is fine.

Comment: Thinking again, I suspect that swapping a value with itself is actually **not** atomic, because you've actually read the value twice. That could be the cause of a really horrible subtle bug!

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

Testing equality *is* atomic, insomuch as it is thread safe, but it only checks equality at that point in time. A fraction of a second one way or the other and the value you're comparing might have a different value. In particular, this is *not* a constant function because it uses hidden data that might change.

That said, I would use `==` here because your swap looks pointless.

---

Edit:

The point is that it's the variable *load* that needs to be atomic, not any of the other stuff.

Here's what your routine does:

1. Receives some values in registers.
2. Loads an integer from memory.
3. Edits some values in registers.
4. Returns.

There's only one thing there that has any bearing on concurrency: the load. The value of the counter may be changing continuously, but your routine cannot do anything special about that. Even with locking, the best it can do is load the current value and work with what it has.

It might be that the value has changed by the time the function returns, but all the code could ever hope to do is say whether it matched the value at the point it looked. It would be the responsibility of the *caller* to make sure that that's a valid thing to do (i.e. that nothing would update the counter until it was done).

A load of a struct, or an array, vector, or any other multi-value type would require that you acquire a read-lock to ensure that what you get is self-consistent (that the first bit you read corresponds to the last bit you read). But a load of an integer is pretty certain to be atomic (though not *actually* guaranteed by C/C++) so you need not worry.

The equality operator, `==`, operates only on the contents of your function's own context (registers and stack), and so there are no concurrency problems (unless you took an address of your stack variable and sent it to another thread).

Comment: Testing equality is neither atomic or non-atomic. Reading and writing operations can be atomic or not. So, this boils down to whether or not reading the contended value is atomic. That is platform dependent.

Comment: True, a vector read might be a problem. But we're talking `int` here.

Comment: In your comment to the other answer you state "The number of read instructions per value is all that matters." You should really say so in your answer. It's a key point. As for atomicity of reading `int`, the standard won't ensure that. It is platform dependent.

Comment: Whilst that's technically true, I'm pretty sure the world would fall apart if you couldn't be sure an integer load was self consistent. I'll update the answer as you suggest.

Comment: If the `int` is not aligned correctly on x86 then reading is not atomic

Comment: That's worth knowing when dealing with packed structs.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing 2 volatile variables is never mutexless atomic (I think you mean this), because you have to load the variables everytime from memory and cannot handle them in registers. The comparison is on most architectures done by substracting both and checking the zero value. This are at least 3 instructions.

The question for atomicity is only needed here, if there are decisions to make, because of any relation between two values. Because of the volatility of the values, you have to poll these values. Then atomicity of the comparison makes no sense, because if you won't succeed the equality in this turn you will get it in the next turn, but there is no gurantee that you will hit every equality. So in this sense, you comparison with `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` makes no sense.

Comment: The number of instructions in the comparison is irrelevant. The number of read instructions per value is all that matters. Register values are reliable; it's memory values that are not.

Comment: The question is, if there is any platform, where loading two values and jumping in case of equality is one atomic instruction. I know no such platform.

Comment: @PennyStock Again, the comparison and jump are not relevant to the question of atomicity. Loads of integer-sized values are atomic, and this example only does **one** load. The other value  comes from a function parameter.