# Do I need to protect the read on a variable that is only modified in the same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let us consider two or more threads, and a resource. Should this be relevant, I am using C++11 on Ubuntu.
The situation is illustrated by the following code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class Res
{
    //Data
};

void use_resource(const Res& rsc) {/*Do stuff*/}
void modify_resource(Res& rsc) {/*Modify the resource*/}

class A
{
    Res resource;
    std::mutex resource_mtx;
    std::thread thd;

    public:
    A()
    {
        thd = std::thread(&A::loop,this);      
    }

    void loop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            use_resource(resource); //(Case 1)

            //Some work

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlock(resource_mtx);
                modify_resource(resource); //(Case 2)
            }
        }
    }

    Res get_resource()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlock(resource_mtx);
        return resource; //(Case 3)
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;


    while(true)
    {
        Res res1 = a.get_resource();

        //Do stuff with the resource
    }
}
```

We have a resource that contains some data. The function *loop()* in A runs on the first thread only. The other threads can call *get_resource()* to get access to the resource. The resource can only be modified by the function *modified_resource*.
My understanding is that there is a need for a lock in cases 2 and 3, since case 2 involves a write, and case 3 a read from another thread.

What I would like to know is if there is a need for a lock in case 1. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model), the definition of a data race seems to be:

> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and
>   another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the
>   expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting
>   evaluations has a data race unless:
>   i) both evaluations execute on the same thread or in the same signal handler, or
>   ii) both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see std::atomic), or
>   iii) one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before another (see std::memory_order)

I would think that there is no data race for case 1 in my code from those definitions:
There is no conflict between 1) and 2) (they are on the same thread, i) applies).
There is no conflict between 1) and 3) (none of them is a write).

This leads me to my two questions:
Q1) In the specific code provided, is there a need to protect the call to *use_resource* (Case 1) by a lock on *resource_mtx* to avoid a data race ?
Q2) Same question if this time cases 1 and 2 can be repeated, in any order or number, in the *loop()* function ? An arbitrary example would be:

```
while(true)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlock(resource_mtx);
        modify_resource(resource); //(Case 2)
    }
    use_resource(resource); //(Case 1)      
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlock(resource_mtx);
        modify_resource(resource); //(Case 2)
    }
    use_resource(resource); //(Case 1)
    use_resource(resource); //(Case 1)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlock(resource_mtx);
        modify_resource(resource); //(Case 2)
    }
}
```

As said above, my guess would be that there is no need for a lock in both cases, but I might very well be missing something, like compiler reordering or even the actual definition of a data race.

So far, I have only seen questions about read only access from a separate thread, which is my case 2, ([there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834752/multithreading-do-i-need-protect-my-variable-in-read-only-method) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420665/multithreading-with-a-global-variable-if-only-one-thread-is-changing-the-variab)) or interactions between two different threads ([there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016806/in-which-cases-do-i-need-to-lock-a-variable-from-simultaneous-access)), but I have not seen this specific problem of read only access in the same thread.

EDIT: Edited the code to actually reflect a multithreaded scenario.

Comment: when you dont do multithreading your program runs in a single thread. maybe that already answers your question...

Comment: A single thread can only do one thing at a time. It can't both read from and write to a variable simultaneously.

Comment: Maybe my example was not clear then, sorry about that. While the loop indeed runs on a single thread, there are other threads with access to class A that run on separated threads. Those other threads can call *get_resource* while the loop is running.

Comment: btw I was not trying to be snarky. Irrespective of my comment, I think this is a completely valid quesiton. Correctly synchronizing data is by no means simple. I have to admit, I dont have time to read your code in detail. Would be good if you can turn it into a [mcve]

Comment: Your title threw me off as well. In your case *yes* you need to protect the variable, since it can be accessed simultaneously by different threads.

Comment: If only one thread modifies the value of a variable, you don't have to protect the reads from the variable in this same thread. I'd say there is no need to lock the mutex in Case 1.

Comment: I have edited the original code sample so that it better reflects the problem, sorry if this was misleading before. It should now be a proper minimal example.

Comment: @Culbuto Why do you say it can only be modified by the same thread if it can be modified by threads other than the ones reading?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In my case, the loop function is only supposed to be called in one thread, the one called in the constructor of A. I should probably make the loop function private to better reflect that in the code. Then it should not be possible for other threads to modify the resource, since only the loop calls modify_resource.

Comment: @Culbuto The issue is not whether or not other threads can modify the resource. The issue is whether the resource can be accessed in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree. In this case, there should be no issue (as long as loop only runs on one thread), since 1) and 2) run on the same thread, and 2) and 3) are protected by a mutex. If loop() is launched from a second thread, there is indeed a data race. What I meant by "only modified by the same thread" is that the only non protected read happens necessarily on the same thread as the write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample you are "safe" (assuming correct `Res`).

Problematic cases happen when `2)` (the write operation) would execute concurrently with `1)` / `2)` or `3)` (without synchronization).
`1)` and `3)` might happens concurrently, as read only.

`1)` and `2)` are in the same thread, so cannot happen concurrently with `2)`.
`3)` and `2)` are protected by `mutex`.

Note that if in `3)`, you don't create copy but return reference, then `3)` `mutex` would be not extended correct scope.